# Can't set new value inside updateOne hooks in Mongoose while updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a `user` schema that when i add a new one to the database it hashes the `password` in the `pre(save)` hook but i want to do the same while updating but it saves the plain password instead of hashed one

this works fine while creating new record

```
UserSchema.pre('save', async function (done) {
  if (this.isModified('password')) {
    const hashedPassword = await Password.hash(this.get('password'));
    this.set('password', hashedPassword);
  }

  done(null);
});
```

but this didn't work fine

```
UserSchema.pre('updateOne', async function (done) {
  const hashedPassword = await Password.hash(this.get('password'));
  this.set('password', hashedPassword);

  done(null);
});
```

> NOTE: there are no errors in the console

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre if you define pre('updateOne') document middleware, this will be the document being updated. That's because pre('updateOne') document middleware hooks into Document#updateOne() rather than Query#updateOne(), so it should be schema.pre('updateOne', { document: true, query: false }, function() {
  console.log('Updating');
})

Comment: @Nonik still not working too

Comment: @Nonik it works after adding `this.save()` thanks a lot, add it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)

if you define pre('updateOne') document middleware, this will be the document being updated. That's because pre('updateOne') document middleware hooks into Document#updateOne() rather than Query#updateOne(), so it should be

```
schema.pre('updateOne', { document: true, query: false }, function() { console.log('Updating'); })
```

Comment: If i could up vote twice, I would...thank you